# What kind of date format?

Tags: php, datetime

I got the source data,and in their source contains date with this format

`2011-01-12T14:41:35.7042252+01:00`

I don't know which is format of date they are using.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

its **[ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date (added in PHP 5)**

you  can get it using `c` in `date('c')`  return **2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00**

**additional Note:**

by using `r` ;`date('r')` you will get date like this  **Thu, 21 Dec 2000 16:01:07 +0200**

**[REFERNECE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)**

Comment: if echo  date('c') we got  2011-05-27T10:31:00+02:00 .but look missing seconds.decimal-fraction-of-second.You know how to get display it?

Comment: i check back to date manul where this is written :using `u` we will get  Microseconds (**added in PHP 5.2.2**) `Example: 654321` ; although i dont know how to apply this with `c` may be use `mktime()`

Comment: I am trying with strtotime but can not got expected result yet.

Comment: @newbie why u want such format? u can not get both things together

Answer (score 3):

I'll break 2`011-01-12T14:41:35.7042252+01:00` down:

```
2011-01-12 = yyyy-mm-dd
```

`T` means Time is next

```
14:41 = hh:mm

35.7042252 = seconds.decimal-fraction-of-second
```

`+01:00 = timezone` e.g. UTC plus 1 hour.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime for details.